# How do I apply the distributive law for the vector equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

How do I apply the distributive law for the equation $$xA - xBA = 0$$ where $x$ is a vector, $A$ and $B$ are matrices?

I can see two ways of doing this but I can't see how both of them can be true at the same time.

1. $x(A - BA) = 0$
2. $(x - xB)A = 0$

Comment: Why not? Another equivalent form is $3. \ \textbf x(\textbf I-\textbf B)\textbf A=0$.

Comment: If I take a solution of the equation from the first form, A = BA, shouldn't it be a solution to the second form as well?

Comment: Yes, $A=BA\Rightarrow B=I$ This holds for all three equations.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. For the sake of completeness $x=A=0$ are solutions as well.

Comment: @callculus42 Note that for non-invertible $A$ this implication is false in general.

Comment: @martini Thanks for the comment. I've omitted other details as well.